# JAX-WS client: UnsupportedMediaException for gzipped response

Tags: java, jax-ws, gzip

I wrote JAX-WS (from Sun) client which makes service calls which expect server responses to be gzipped:

```
Map<String, List<String>> theHeaders = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
theHeaders.put("Content-Encoding", Collections.singletonList("gzip"));
theHeaders.put("Accept", Collections.singletonList("application/x-gzip"));
theHeaders.put("Accept-Encoding", Collections.singletonList("gzip, deflate"));
theHeaders.put("Content-Type", Collections.singletonList("application/x-gzip"));
((BindingProvider) client).getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, theHeaders);
```

According to the Fiddler, response is HTTP 200 (Ok) and soap response is gzipped.
Still, I'm getting the following error:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type: application/x-gzip Supported ones are: [application/soap+xml]
at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:322)
at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAP12Codec.decode(StreamSOAP12Codec.java:107)
at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:156)
at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:312)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:295)
```

I [read](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/jitu/archive/2007/07/jaxws_ri_and_co_1.html) that JAX-WS should support gzipped webservice responses out of the box, but it looks like it doesn't. It tries to use default codec which is for application/soap+xml despite the fact response contains Content-Type: application/x-gzip header.

Is there a way to make it use another codec, for gzip? Is there such a codec?

Answer (score 0):

The link you referred to is telling that it supports gzip when the response is sent with

```
Content-encoding: gzip
```

header, in addition to standard content-type header. If the server responds with `Content-Type: application/x-gzip`, it's a different header, and it doesn't seem that would be supported even though gzip in itself is supported. I don't think you should be setting this:

```
theHeaders.put("Accept", Collections.singletonList("application/x-gzip"));
```

instead, just set accept-encoding including gzip:

```
theHeaders.put("Accept", Collections.singletonList("application/soap+xml"));
theHeaders.put("Content-Type", Collections.singletonList("application/soap+xml"));
theHeaders.put("Accept-Encoding", Collections.singletonList("gzip"));
theHeaders.put("Content-Encoding", Collections.singletonList("gzip"));
```

Comment: So, just to be sure I didn't get it wrong: the server side should response _exactly_ with the gzip content-encoding header, not application/x-gzip to make it treated as a gzip on the client side?

Comment: @MikhailBerastau application/gzip is a content-type header value, gzip is application-encoding header value. So, for all implementations, server should respond with content-encoding gzip for this to work. For some web service client libraries it is ok to use *also* application/gzip content type - for some it is not. I was making a guess, based on the error message, that in this case it is not.

Comment: checked the sources of jaxws-rt, it makes comparison like this: 
    if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.contains("gzip")) {
        in = new GZIPInputStream(in);
    }
so any mention of gzip in content-encoding is acceptable; re content-type - I think you are right and it should be application/soap+xml.

Comment: In my case the problem is the contentEncoding variable is null (checked by debugging) even having Content-Encoding set correctly in respond.

Comment: yes, any mention should be acceptable. I put it as only one as you indicated that gzip is the one you want to use.

Comment: so you mean content-encoding is set, response is gzipped, but contentEncoding variable is null? that sounds peculiar. would need more code in the question to comment, though.